# Responsive design, viewport issue

Tags: css, wordpress

I have an issue with responsive design on my site. The problem is that, when the page is loaded, I can see the "the mobile look" but its zoomed out. I think it's a problem that my page has some element which sets the width to some large number. Because of that I have a horizontal slider and a large empty white area on the right side of the screen.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Site is at http://www.studentskizivot.com/

I used viewport at header.php (head)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

@media code :

```
html{
background:none!important;
width:100%;
}
#text-51, #text-79, #polls-widget-7 {
display:none;
}
#bglink{
display:none;
}
body {
background:none!Important;
margin:0px auto;
}
#footercontent .footerboxlast{
margin-top:15px;
}
#footercontent .footerbox {
width: 209px;
display: block;
clear: both;
float: left;
margin: 15px 16px 0px 0px;
border: #FF0000 solid 0;
padding: 0;
background: url(images/skin1/footer_bgrdbox.png);
font-family: "Open Sans";}
nav#primary-navigation{margin-top:15px;}
#header-widget-area{display:none;}
#topbar{padding: 0.4em 0.8em;}
#secondary-navigation select.tinynav{
font-size:1.4rem;}
div#main div#content div#wdsi-slide_in.wdsi-slide div.wdsi-slide-wrap{
display:none!important;
}
.logo-image-enabled #site-title {
line-height: 1.5;
width: 100%;
}
#topbar{width:100%!important;}
.logo-image-enabled #site-title { line-height: 1.5; width: 100%; }
.logo-image-enabled #branding{padding:0px;}
.topbar-enabled #header{background:#EEEEEE;}
#topbar{line-height:14px}
#topbar{padding: 0.4em 0.8em;}

}
```

Also , when I open the page in firefox for android, many of these css rules do not apply. Opera, Chrome, Maxton, all work well, but firefox is messy. Any clues why?

many, many thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your source code, there is an element that has an inline style with a width of 1041px. Once you remove that your site is good. It's the last element in "#footer".

```
<div style="height:8px; width:1041px; background:#fff; position: relative; float:left;"></div>
```

Comment: all good now, a leftover from previous site.... One more thing, do you perhaps know why firefox, when shrinked (simulation of mobile view on PC) or opened in firefox for android, does not apply css code from @media and (max-width:520px (example)). Chrome works Thx!

Comment: Do you mean with the top nav bar? If that's the problem, on line 465 of http://www.studentskizivot.com/wp-content/themes/fearless/style.css?ver=1.6.2 change "width: 1064px;" to "max-width:100%;"